# Add data to ICollection<T>

Tags: c#

I have model which contains a list of objects of a certain interface:

```
public class Header : IRequestHeaderModel
{
   /// Other properties
   ICollection<IRequestBodyModel> IRequestHeaderModel.Items
   {
       get { return this.Items.Cast<IRequestBodyModel>().ToList(); } //Is creating a brand new list every time. Adding to this won't affect the list you get the next time you call get. 
       set { this.Items = value.Cast<MyRequestBodyModel>().ToList(); }
   }
   public ICollection<MyRequestBodyModel> Items { get; set; } //ok to add
}
```

Now I want to be able to call the `Add` method on my properties `Items` and `IRequestHeaderModel.Items`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: They are not the same. One can request the list from your explicit interface implementation (`ICollection<IRequestBodyModel> IRequestHeaderModel.Items`), and add something that implements `IRequestBodyModel` but isn't a `MyRequestBodyModel`. The second property can't accept such items.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to add to `ICollection<IRequestBodyModel> IRequestHeaderModel.Items` as you could add items like `class Foo : IRequestBodyModel { }`.

Comment: It also isn't a good practice to let external code set the collection anyway.

Comment: @Enigmativity `IRequestHeaderModel` is inherited by two other object. They have same logic but there are properties that uniquely to them. So I'm trying to create abstract that will can accommodate the logic.

Comment: @Vic - That's a bad design.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to add to `ICollection<IRequestBodyModel> IRequestHeaderModel.Items` as you could add items like `class Foo : IRequestBodyModel { }`.

It also isn't a good practice to let external code set the collection anyway.

This is a better implementation of your code:

```
public class Header : IRequestHeaderModel
{
    IEnumerable<IRequestBodyModel> IRequestHeaderModel.Items
    {
        get { return this.Items.Cast<IRequestBodyModel>(); }
    }
    public ICollection<MyRequestBodyModel> Items { get; private set; }
}

public interface IRequestHeaderModel
{
    IEnumerable<IRequestBodyModel> Items { get; }
}
```

Comment: This is a common scenario though (which the OP should have explained): the class contains a property with a collection of a concrete type, for serialization/storage purposes (think Entity Framework or Web API). Now there _also_ is a business layer, that prescribes that such entities should implement a certain interface (and that interface prescribes a property with a collection of interface types). Now the model should map between the two. The actual solution is to abandon this approach and not use your storage / DTO classes as business models.

Comment: In other words, there is another class in the business layer which wants to retrieve `IRequestBodyModel`s from somewhere, and add them to an `IRequestHeaderModel`'s `Items` collection property. People think they're decoupling things with this design, while they're actually coupling their model to two layers instead of making it layer-agnostic.

Comment: @CodeCaster do have sample code or link that can I studied?